# How to replace part of a string in SQLite using Regex?

Tags: sql, sqlite

If i have the following string:

**I WOULD LIKE TO USE REGEXP TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM AND NOT THE DEFINED WORD**

**"123456abcd"** and **"123456"**

I would like to find and replace where the numbers 123456 appear in that order, i know that regex has to be used in SQlite but I cannot seem to find which function to use (either REPLACE or UPDATE).

For example in the above - I would like to replace 123456 with the string "cheese" - then I would like the following:

"cheeseabcd" and "cheese"

I am stuck on how to solve this in SQL lite! everytime I make a change it changes the entire string and not just part of the string!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any regular expressions here.  Just:

```
replace(col, '123456', cheese)
```

Comment: how can i use regexp to solve this problem - i may need to match not only 123 but some other combo any help?

Comment: @A.F . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a *different* question, ask it as a *new* question, with appropriate sample data and desired results.